# Neo4j: From given start node find all paths that touch all relations

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

using Neo4j, I'm working on a very simple model that consists of five nodes A..E and eight relations between them. For a given start node I want to get all paths that touch every relation of the model. Each relation must be touched once.

My code looks as follows:

```
TraversalDescription traversal = Traversal.description().uniqueness( Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL);

Traverser t = traversal.traverse( getNode("C"));
for ( Path position : t )
{
    if( position.length() == 8 ) {
        System.out.println("Solution found");
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the traverser does not return all possible paths of length eight but only one.

Is there a way to tell the Traverser or the TraversalDescription to throw out all paths?

Thanks,
Olli

Comment: @Illimaus, why don't you try `Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_PATH` or even `Uniqueness.NONE`?

Comment: Hi tstorms, Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_PATH made it work :)

I'm also working on the Evalutor based suggestion, but can't get it working right now, need to study it...
Regards, Olli

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried useing [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html) queries for that ? it may be something like

```
start n = node:someIndex(name='C') match p=n-[RELATION*8]->(x) return x, length(p)
```

You may also try to use [Evaluators](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/Evaluators.html), it may help you to find paths with a certain depth.

```
Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
return path.length() == 8 ? Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE : Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE);
 }
```

I wish it help you..